# Why is my Ngx-qrcode2 not generating a QR Code in Angular?

Tags: npm, jhipster, qr-code, angular7

I've been stuck on this problem for almost 3 days now. So what I'm currently trying to do, is display a QR Code on a page that takes you to a URL. For this, I'm using `ngx-qrcode2`.

So far, I've already tried running an `npm install ngx-qrcode2 --save`. Then, I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bsrqHcb-hQ, even generating another angular app, and following exactly what he did. It still doesn't work. After running it, my console displayed the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'qrc-value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-qr-code'.
```

Also, on my own app that I have been working on to generate a QR Code, it doesn't display a QR Code, but the difference is that it doesn't display any console errors either. This is separate from the QR Code app I tried generating.

Here's some of my code from the QR Code generated app:

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'qra-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<h1>Visit this site.</h1>
<ngx-qr-code qrc-element-type="url" [qrc-value]="value"></ngx-qr-code>
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxQRCodeModule } from 'ngx-qrcode2';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxQRCodeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My other app also has the exact same thing.

Also, if it helps, here's my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "qrcode",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-qrcode2": "0.0.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

At this point, I'm not sure what else to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's the tag your using not correct. It's suppose to be <ngx-qrcode> not <ngx-qr-code>.

Comment: i have the same problem, have you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

The npm package  ngx-qrcode2 has been deprecated. Use @techiediaries/ngx-qrcode instead.

Try installing

```
npm install @techiediaries/ngx-qrcode --save
```

Here's link for updated package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@techiediaries/ngx-qrcode

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same error.

As [Manab said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62009198/10251345), it is deprecated. So use [value] instead of [qrc-value]:

```
<ngx-qrcode [value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
```